# Custom function in Laravel return NULL but on var_dump is not NULL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have custom class in laravel 5.4 app which should return hashed secret. The class is

```
class Hash {

   // Unencrypted secret

   private $secret;

   public function generateSecret(){

       $secret = generateSecretKey();

       $secret_hash = password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

       Session::put('secret-hash', $secret_hash);
       $this->secret = $secret;        
   }
}
```

Then in my controller I have

```
use Hash;
class UsersController extends BaseController
{
    public function Auth()
    {
        $myhash = new Hash();
        $msg = '';

        $myhash->generateSecret();
        $enc = $myhash->encryptSecret($key->key);
        return View::make('users.auth', ['enc'=> $enc]);
    }
     ...
}
```

`var_dump($myhash->generateSecret());` from the controller return `NULL`

`var_dump($secret)` in `public function generateSecret()` return `string(15) "866094233422231" string(15) "583375207466239"` which is correct.

`var_dump($myhash);` in UsersController also return correct data

```
String(15) "008844975703088" object(Hash)#329 (1) 
{ 
     ["secret":"Hash":private]=> string(15) "008844975703088" 
}
```

Appears that the problem is in controller and generating the hash `$myhash->generateSecret();`. The function must generate secret(a string) which then is hashed `$enc = $myhash->encryptSecret($key->key);` and displayed on page.

Any ideas why the function isn't working? I don't know what else I can try.

Comment: I think `var_dump` shows null because your function has no return.

Comment: Yeah, I think same but then when I var dump it directly in the function it is showing the result and it is not null which is odd for me.

Comment: return the value of your function generateSecret.

Comment: @aldrin27, this is the example return of `generateSecret` - `string(15) "866094233422231" string(15) "583375207466239"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generateSecret()` does not return anything, so `$myhash->generateSecret()` is `NULL`.  `generateSecret()` *does* set `$secret` as a property (`$this->secret = $secret`), but since `$secret` is declared as private, you can't access it outside the class, so `$myhash->secret` in your controller won't work.

So you have 2 options - either return the secret so the calling code can see it, or add a getter to make `$secret` accessible outside the class.  Here's how you could return it:

```
public function generateSecret(){
    $secret = generateSecretKey();
    $secret_hash = password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    Session::put('secret-hash', $secret_hash);
    return $secret;
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$secret = $myhash->generateSecret();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay. I will try it this way and will let you know about the result.

Comment: Just a question: What can be the reason to work on my local server but not online?

Comment: Sorry but is still bool(false). I mean I don't get NULL in the controller anymore but now I get `bool(false)`

Comment: I am not sure what your code looks like now, but does `$secret` still come from `generateSecretKey()`?  If yes, then `generateSecretKey()` is returning  `false` ... try `var_dump()` again to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The second bool(false) was my mistake. Everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

This function:

```
public function generateSecret()
{

   $secret = generateSecretKey();

   $secret_hash = password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

   Session::put('secret-hash', $secret_hash);
   $this->secret = $secret;        
}
```

Doesn't return any data, so `var_dump($myhash->generateSecret());` will always be null.

You should expose state using getter if you need to access it outside of class.

Comment: I don't understand because this function is working perfectly like this in laravel **4.2**.

Comment: Sorry but doesn't I have getter in my user controller where I have `$myhash = new Hash();`

Comment: No, that's just instantiating your class.  Either add a getter which returns `$this->secret`, or simply `return $secret;` from `generateSecret()`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, `return $secret;` doesn't change anything. Maybe I'm wrong but I just replaced `$this->secret = $secret;` with `return $secret;`, right?

Comment: I added an answer with more details.